# NSArray.count returns incorrect, giant integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsarray

I have the following code, intended to select a random string from the array.

```
NSArray *popupMessages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"Shoulda' been bobbin' and weaving! Need anything from the shop?",
                          @"Don't forget you can use old boss's guns! Available in the shop!",
                          @"Hey Chaz, you Bojo! You need more POWER! Come by the shop for some better weapons!",
                          @"Aw… lame. Maybe I got something that can help you out here at my shop!",

                          nil];
int pmCount = popupMessages.count; // Breakpoint Here - pmCount = 971056545

int messageIndex = arc4random() % pmCount; // Breakpoint Here - same as above
```

I am using ARC with cocos2d. Any ideas as to why the array's count returns such a huge number? Thanks!

Comment: Uh, good question considering I just copied your code verbatim and it showed up fine for me.

Comment: Oh really? Thank you for doing that then - that confirms that it's probably something related to xcode, etc., perhaps a variable conflict.

Comment: That was my first thought, maybe you have popupMessages declared as a property and it's being synthesized as _popupMessages but you're using popupMessages without self? Or something? Maybe? First step is just rename the array and see what happens.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a debugger artifact?  Add a log statement.

Comment: @CarlNorum I hadn't even considered that - I'll give that a try right now.

Comment: FWIW I got it to print in log and in debugger using po pmCount and po popupMessages.count

Comment: @CarlNorum that must have been what it was - I'll have to look into those. If you'd like to submit the debugger artifact thing as an answer, I'll accept it. Quitting and restarting XCode fixed this.

Comment: well that was anti-climactic. classic have you turned it off and on again.

Comment: @rocky you're telling me. I spent about 15 minutes scrambling, trying to figure it out, when I could have just restarted in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem just looks like it's a debugger artifact.  It could be optimization-related, for example. Sometimes compilers can generate code that confuses debuggers pretty seriously.  Add a log statement to make sure the debugger isn't just telling you lies.

Comment: Thanks again - I will be sure to try logging stuff first in the future.

Comment: @XenElement - Learn how to use the debug console commands.  Eg, while stopped on a breakpoint on your second line type `p (int) [popupMessages count]` to display the count.  Much more reliable than the debug variable display (which I hardly use anymore, due to its flakiness).

Comment: @HotLicks oooh good to know - I'll have to look those up as well.

Comment: @XenElement Just out of curiosity, how were you printing it with debugger?

Comment: I was simply reading what was shown in the "Debug Area" when it stopped at a breakpoint. In my Xcode, it is at the bottom of the screen to the left of the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

["`count`" is not a property, AFAIK](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/count).

The way I usually get the count for an array is:

```
[popupMessages count];
```

Comment: okay downvoters...  I'm looking at the .h file now to be certain.

Comment: It is, definitively... If not, the compiler would have warn.

Comment: nope, I don't see a "`@property`" anywhere in the NSArray.h header file in Foundation.  It *might* work for you for some reason (e.g. maybe some magic that comes with using Cocos2D), but if the O.P. uses "`[popupMessages count]`", s/he will get a better result.

Comment: I understand your reasoning in this answer - I've seen quite a few regarding .count vs count] while searching before asking my question. I've always used .count without any issues, and it's possible that it is an unofficial property or something - not quite sure. Definitely doesn't merit a down vote though.

Comment: Right, it isn't declared as an explicit property... But I don't think that's the issue. Since the compiler allow it, it will just call the count method... Removed my down vote, though...

Comment: change "`int`" to "`NSUInteger` and change "`array`" to "`popupMessages`" (just in case you hadn't done that already) and let me know if that works better.

Comment: Nothing to do, with 4 elements a cast to `int` will never cause a loss of precision.

Comment: If `popupMessages.count` didn't work about half the apps in the App Store wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSInteger pmCount = [popupMessages count];
```

Comment: I don't think you want that `*`.

Comment: First of all his array has just 4 elements. Assigning the result of `count` to an `int` will surely not cause a loss of precision, tough is good practice to don't use an `int`, but neither a `NSInteger`, because the count property returns a `NSUInteger`.